# Integral of Weibull distribution

Tags: integration

How would you find the distribution function for the following density functions (Weibull function):

$$f_{X}(x) = c\tau x^{\tau−1}e^{− cx^{\tau}} $$

for $0< x < \infty$, $\tau > 0$ and $c>0$.

Comment: Is the edit by johnny OK? I'm guessing it should actually be $$f_{X}(x) = c\tau x^{\tau−1}e^{− cx^{\tau}} $$ Am I right?

Comment: Certainly looks more Weibullish your way, @PeterTamaroff. :)

Comment: Are you looking to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty f_X(x)\text{ ? }$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So $$F_X(x)=\int_0^x c\tau s^{\tau−1}e^{− cs^{\tau}} ds\\
= c\tau \int_0^x s^{\tau−1}e^{− cs^{\tau}} ds
$$

If we use the substitution $s^{\tau}=u$, and $\frac{du}{ds}=\tau s^{\tau-1}$ this simplifies to

$$c\int_0^{x^\tau} e^{− cu} du\\
=\left[-e^{-cu}\right]_0^{x^\tau}\\
=1-e^{-cx^{\tau}}.$$

I hope that I've not given this to you too easily and that this is useful to you.

$\textbf{EDIT}$: I have assumed you were asking for the c.d.f. but the other commenters are correct your question is not entirely clear on its terminology. Also fixed my $\LaTeX$.

Comment: thank you for editing and answering the question simon. I am new to this forum and didn't know how to write the question in the correct form

Comment: That's ok. Is this answer what you wanted? Don't forget you can accept the answer as correct by clicking the tick icon on the left side of it.

Comment: Ah that special feeling of rejection when you put up the right answer and you don't get a tick or even an upvote.

Comment: Yaaaaay! Thanks! It makes it worth doing :)

Comment: Your welcome. Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: @Simon Hayward If you take $u=s^{\tau}$ then you change also the limits, and the result then becomes, $1-e^{-cx^{\tau}}$ or not ?