# Finding integral of modified Weibull density

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For two constants, $a,b$ I am interested in the following integral:

$$\int_0^{b-a} \frac{k}{\lambda} \bigg(\frac{y}{\lambda}\bigg)^{k-1}
 \exp \bigg[-\big(\frac{y}{\lambda}\big)^k - \big(\frac{(b-y)}{\theta}\big)^l \bigg] dy$$

The first part of the integral up to the second term in the exponent is equivalent to a Weibull density with [easy to derive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253804/integral-of-weibull-distribution) definite integral. I am not sure if it is possible to handle the second term in the exponent in closed form. Do you have any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Mathematica gives an answer in terms of hypergeometric functions so this may not be an integral that is readily solved by hand.